# Construction of *ZFC

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, model-theory, nonstandard-analysis

In the following [paper](http://www.dm.unipi.it/~dinasso/papers/05.pdf), page 11 (Appendix), there is a construction of a model of a theory $^*ZFC$ (see the definitions in the paper included) from a model of $ZFC$. I have been trying really hard to understand it for almost a month without fruition. I have 4 questions.

The construction supposes that when we have a direct limit of $\in$-structures $(\mathcal{U}_i,\epsilon_i)_{i\in I}$ (where for all $i$ in $I$, $U_i$ is a class), with end-extensions $\chi_{i,j}$, then the direct limit $(\mathcal{U}_\gamma,\epsilon_\gamma)$

1/ is a class
2/ verifies the following property for $x$ in $U_\gamma$ : $\{x'\in U_\gamma | x'\epsilon_\gamma x\}$ is a set. How is it proved ?

Then the author procedes and defines the direct limit of classes indexed by the ordinals. 3/ The class of the ordinals being a proper class, how can one give a meaning to it ?

Finally, supposing that the structure $<U_d,\epsilon_d>$ exists, 4/ how can we prove that $<U_d,\epsilon_d>$ is a model of $ZFC^-$ ? First, the class does not seem to verify the extensionality axiom. The paper says the proof is "similar" to the proof of the fact that a transitive class $C$ that verifies "for all x which is a set, $x\subset C \Rightarrow x\in C$" is a model of $ZFC^-$. In what way is it similar ?

Answer (score 1):

It may be a typo, but you write $(\mathcal{U}_\gamma, \varepsilon_\gamma)$ is a direct *product* where the paper talks about a direct *limit*.

It is clearly important that the proof comes in two stages and the set $I$ is only needed for the first one. The second stage does not invoke an arbitrary collection of classes $(\mathcal{U}_i)_{i \in I}$, but a parameterised family $(\mathcal{U}_\alpha)_{\alpha \in \text{On}}$ indexed over the class of ordinals; there is a single formula $\Phi(x, \gamma)$ which identifies membership of $\mathcal{U}_\gamma$ whenever $\gamma$ is an ordinal.

Indeed $\Phi$ can express "there is a set $Y$ with elements indexed by $\gamma+1$ such that $Y_0$ verifies $Y_0 \in \text{V}^I_D$, for every $\delta < \gamma$ we have $Y_{\delta + 1}\, \subset\, Y_\delta$, for every limit $\delta \leq \gamma$ $Y_\delta$ is contained in the union of the previous elements of $Y$, and $x$ is equal to $Y_\gamma$."

Then the union $\mathcal{U}_D = \cup(\mathcal{U}_\alpha)$ is also a class, simply by quantifying out the parameter $\gamma$; $x \in \mathcal{U}_D$ iff $\exists \gamma \in \text{On} \, x \in \mathcal{U}_\gamma$.

I've left out the relations $\varepsilon_\gamma$, mostly out of laziness but the construction of the verifying formula mentioning them as well would proceed in exactly the same way. Up to laziness this should answer your question 1.

The critical point is that the $\varepsilon_\gamma$ are a class linked by end-extensions, with the property that any pair of them are always consistent on their joint domain. So we can relativise any relation $a\,\varepsilon\,b$ to any $\mathcal{U}_\gamma$ large enough that both elements appear, and it does not matter which.

For your question 2, we can take the successor $\mathcal{U}_{\gamma+1}$ of any $\mathcal{U}_\gamma$ in which $x$ exists, and the desired set will be in this successor and therefore in the union class $\mathcal{U}_D$.

Your question 3 again asks how a union of proper classes can be a class, and I am not sure how this differs from your question 1. Again the point is that the union is over a parametrised family, and the formula defining the union class is simply found by quantifying over the parameter.

Question 4 asks why this union class satisfies Extensionality (as expressed with $\varepsilon$). I am a bit hazy on this---not having a month to work through it---but the answer must lie in the exact definition of $\varepsilon_\gamma$ in conjuction with the end-extensions $\chi$. Note that $\varepsilon_\gamma$ is defined in terms of the genuine subset operation $\subset$, so presumably Extensionality is inherited from the true property of ZFC.

Comment: I indicated a set $I$ for the direct product because there is, during the transfinite recursion, the step of the limit ordinals where we take the direct limit of the structures. How exactly is the direct limit constructed ? If we do the quotient of the structures by the relation indicated in wikipedia in the article direct limit, how can we be sure that the result is a class ?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit#Algebraic_objects

Comment: The domain of the limit structure is the union (with respect to the usual relation $\in$) of the domains; the quotient relation is exactly the union of the functions $\chi_{\beta\beta'}$. And the result is a class because, once again, the union is over a *parametrised* family of classes, all defined uniformly by the same formula except for a change of parameter. You can't, obviously, take more than a finite union of arbitrary classes using a finite disjunction of arbitrary formulas, but with a uniform family you can *quantify* over infinitely many values of the parameter.

Comment: Why don't you take as the domain of the limit structure the disjoint union $\bigsqcup_{\alpha <\gamma} U_\alpha$ quotiented by the relation $x \mathcal{R} y$ with $x$ in $U_\alpha$ and $y$ in $U_{\alpha '}$ iff $\exists \beta < \gamma, \chi_{\alpha,\beta}(x)=\chi_{\alpha ',\beta}(y)$ ? You have to take the quotient to guarantee that there are not too many elements. The problem being that $\bigsqcup_{\alpha <\gamma} U_\alpha \bigg/ \mathcal{R}$ may not be a class. How can you say that the quotient relation is exactly the union of the functions ? Is a relation the same as a union of functions ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm being sloppy, but the interaction between the equivalence relation and the family of homomorphisms should be clear from that Wikipedia article. Set-theoretically functions are sets of $\langle \text{object}, \text{image}\rangle$ pairs and a union of functions is a function as long as it's still many-one. The authors do not construct their limit from a disjoint union, and it would be completely artificial (though it can still be done with a parametrised family). In the notation of the Wikipedia page, the union need not be disjoint if $f_ij(x)=x$ wherever $x \in \A_i \cap A_j$.

Comment: I am confused. Can you please formally describe how you construct the direct limit $U_\gamma$ and the maps $\chi_{\alpha,\gamma}$ when gamma is limit ? It was the main difficulty for me of the question I asked.

Comment: As I said earlier, in the language of classes the domain $U_\gamma = \cup_{\delta < \gamma} U_\delta$ and $\chi_{\alpha, \gamma} = \cup_{\delta < \gamma} \chi_{\alpha, \delta}$. In the formal language of set theory (with $\star$ operator) the unions become an existential quantifier. All this is substantially more elementary than the topic of the paper!

Comment: If $\chi_{\alpha,\gamma}=\cup_{\delta<\gamma}\chi_{\alpha,\delta}$, in order to have a map that is defined, we need that, if $x \in U_{\alpha}$, $\chi_{\alpha,\delta}(x)=\chi_{\alpha,\delta'}(x)$ for all $\alpha\leq\delta,\delta'<\gamma$. In particular, $\chi_{\alpha,\alpha}(x)=x=\chi_{\alpha,\delta}(x)$ for all $\delta <\gamma$. This does not seem to be true. Let g the function which is constant equal to $\mathbb{R}$ on I and f the function constant equal to $1$. Clearly, $f,g \in U_0$ and $f \epsilon g$. Hence $f\in \chi_{0,1}(g)$. But $f\not\in g$, then $\chi_{0,1}(g)\ne g$

Comment: No! Your $f$ is a set with elements $\langle x, 1\rangle$ for $x \in I$; your $g$ has elements $\langle x, \mathbb{R}\rangle$. There's no way $f \in g$ or even $f \subset g$. I'd really suggest working through an introduction to axiomatic set theory to get a feel for these methods (I was taught from Enderton's Elements of Set Theory) and dividing the problems you meet into more questions on this site. An extended comments thread on an advanced theorem isn't an ideal way to learn.

Comment: You misread me. $\epsilon$ is an epsilon ($=\epsilon_0$), which is the relation on $V^I_D=U_0$ not a $\in$. I am well aware of set theory. You evoked the possibility of constructing a direct product from a parametrized family of structures which is a class (using the dijoint union of the base set), how do you do that ? If you are tired of reading me, please at least give me a bibliography.